# Can't convert 'Hash' into 'String'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I'm trying to deploy via `capistrano` and for some reason, I'm getting:

```
/Users/mysite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@fbadapter/gems/json-1.4.6/lib/json/common.rb:146:in `initialize': can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)
  from /Users/mysite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@fbadapter/gems/json-1.4.6/lib/json/common.rb:146:in `new'
  from /Users/mysite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@fbadapter/gems/json-1.4.6/lib/json/common.rb:146:in `parse'
  from /Users/mysite/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@fbadapter/gems/chef-capistrano-0.1.0/lib/chef/capistrano.rb:27:in `role_from_chef'
  from ./config/deploy.rb:35:in `block in load'
```

The lines in question of my `config/deploy.rb` are:

```
after 'multistage:ensure' do
 role_from_chef :db, 'app', :limit => 1, :primary => true # perform db operations on one of the app servers
 role_from_chef :web, 'app'
 role_from_chef :app
 role_from_chef :queue
 role_from_chef :cron
end
```

the second line is line 35

**UPDATED CODE**

```
  def role_from_chef(cap_role, *roles)
    %w(chef_host chef_port chef_scheme chef_client_name chef_key_file).each do |value|
      abort "Please set :#{value}" unless exists?(value.to_sym)
    end

    Spice.setup do |s|
      s.host = fetch(:chef_host)
      s.port = fetch(:chef_port)
      s.scheme = fetch(:chef_scheme)
      s.client_name = fetch(:chef_client_name)
      s.key_file = fetch(:chef_key_file)
    end
    Spice.connect!

    options = roles.extract_options!
    roles = [cap_role.to_s] if roles.empty?
    search_roles = fetch(:chef_search_roles) + roles
    query = search_roles.map{|r| "role:#{r}"}.join(" AND ")

    response = Spice.connection.get("/search/node?q=#{URI.encode(query)}")        
    response_object = JSON.parse(response)
    raise response_object['error'].join(' ') if response_object.has_key?('error')

    nodes = response_object['rows']
    hosts = nodes.select{|n| n['ec2']}.map{|n| n['ec2']['public_hostname']}

    if limit = options.delete(:limit)
      hosts = hosts.slice(0, limit)
    end

    hosts.each do |host|
      node = nodes.detect { |n| n['ec2']['public_hostname'] == host }
      puts "#{cap_role}: #{node['ec2']['instance_id']} - #{node['ec2']['public_hostname']}"
    end

    hosts << options
    role cap_role, *hosts
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
role_from_chef :db, 'app', :limit => 1, :primary => true
```

is equivalent to

```
role_from_chef( :db, 'app', { :limit => 1, :primary => true } )
```

As per the error, I would say that you function role_from_chef does accept a String as a third parameter. But without you pasting the role_from_chef function I can't be sure.

Anyhow that's what you should be investigating: follow the third parameter inside role_from_chef and see if it's used as a string somewhere